# how to make several css buttons on the same line fit specified container width

Tags: php, mysql, css

I can't find the answer to this question but it must have been done before.

I have four lines of small images forming "keys" in a sort of kyboard layout (see link):

http://bestmarketingnames.com/Tbanneredit_v53.php

In order to improve SEO the client would like me to use css to create buttons rather than the images that are being used presently.

The client likes the fact that the buttons (or keys) **line up perfectly** with the vertical margin on the **left side and right side** of the container.  For this reason I assume the css/php/mysql must either store width information for the keys or an appropriate percentage must be used that will cause the buttons resize approriately to fill cause the images to **exactly** fill the container div.  Also, if possible, the client would prefer that the keys somewhat match the total width of the words in them.

I am generating the dynamic parts of the page with php/mysql, and am using a single mysql table with 5 columns.

Is there an easy way to use css to create the buttons?  I would prefer to not have to store the css button image widths in the database, but if I have to I can.

Thanks in advance
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Check working DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/UfVhD/3/

## Calculation

button counts in each row = ( number of your buttons/4 )

then,

each button width = ( your content width/button counts in each row) - ( button counts in each row * left right margin 2px )

## CSS

```
ul#myButtons { 
    background:#d6d6d6; 
    padding:5px; 
    float:left; 
    width:920px;}

ul#myButtons li {
    list-style:none; 
    float:left; 
    width:100px; 
    margin:1px; /*Try deleting this float float:left; */
}

ul#myButtons li a { 
    display:block; 
    background:#aaa; 
    color:#444; 
    padding:2px 6px; 
    font:normal 12px Arial; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:1px; 
}
ul#myButtons li a:hover { 
    background:#f0f0f0;
}
```

## HTML

```
<ul id="myButtons">
    <li><a href="#">aaaa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">aaaa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">aaaa</a></li>
    <!-- links go on -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you yeyene. But unfortunately the client that I'm working for is insisting on the edges of the block of buttons line up EXACTLY with each other on the the right edge.  In your example (http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/UfVhD/), if you edit the text in the buttons to be different lengths, the blocks on the right side don't line up exactly with the ones above or below.  I'll edit my question to make that requirement more clear.  Thanks for your work though.

Comment: check again... http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/UfVhD/2/
and you can use above calculation to get the button width

Comment: you can adjust the button width, http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/UfVhD/3/
i used long text button from ur site

Comment: Very nice yeyene.  I will check with the client tomorrow to see if your method is acceptible to him.  It certainly would make it much easier to implement in the database as all the buttons are the same width.  Attempting to duplicate the layout presently done with gifs would be much more complicated I think.  (http://bestmarketingnames.com/Tbanneredit_v53.php)

Comment: I re-read you answer and see I missed the equation part.  So are you proposing that the equation be implemented using the php that the website uses?  If so would I implement that as a property of each individual "mybutton"?

Comment: or simply calsulate by your self and apply to your css button's width?